# Motorized Excavator (8043) set alternatives

Tags: technic, sets, remote-control

I'm on the search for a motorised excavator set and have the 8043 in mind. It is now retired and no longer available.
Are there any alternative currently available sets? I have looked at a few options including motorizing my 42006 set but it doesn't make sense financially.

My second question is, why are LEGO not replacing retired sets with current versions? Is it due to popularity? Design cost vs sales?

Comment: If you're willing to pay a premium, you can find new, sealed sets [on bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8043-1&name=Motorized%20Excavator&category=%5BTechnic%5D%5BModel%5D%5BConstruction%5D#T=S&O={%22cond%22:%22N%22,%22iconly%22:0}).  I've done this from time to time with great success.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid there is no other excavator in LEGO Technic line like 8043. It is quite unique in that it has both driving and its functions motorized. Which is why it keeps its value even on second hand market. In case your collection consist of more than 42006 set you can look into "bricklinking" 8043 set for yourself. That is, look into buying missing bricks to build 8043 set of your own collection. In fact, owning just 42006 set means you already have [45.3% of 8043](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/?1-set=8043-1&1-inv=12610&1-user_list=&2-set=42006-1&2-inv=4880&2-user_list=).

If you are fine with fan designed LEGO model I can suggest looking at [excavators](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/?q=excavator) on Rebrickable. All models have instructions (paid or free).

Answer to why LEGO doesn't keep same type of model for a long period of time is quite simple, I think. If you got excavator released two years ago (which is the usual life span for Technic models), you don't really need a new one. You'd probably want to get dump truck, super car, plane or some other model that you don't already have. And if you already got all the types, and LEGO keeps making sets of the same type you'd probably won't spend money on newer models, which is something LEGO doesn't want to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Whilst I understand the philosophy you have put forward, doesn't this mean that there will be generations gaps? IE the age group who becomes interested lego every 10 or so years don't have the models available to them and so that market is lost? I don't for one minute except Lego to change their business model but its interesting to understand.

Comment: @Jason Not everything that has been popular at certain time may be interesting these days. AFOLs have been asking to reboot Classic Space, Castle, Pirates themes as well as monorail, have more trains and do on for long time. These themes may no longer be popular for today's kids as they were back in the day. However LEGO does listen to their fans and do some smaller releases like Benny's Spaceship, Spaceship, SPACESHIP! (70816), Pirates of Barracuda Bay (21322) and upcoming Medieval Castle (31120) as a follow up on old themes. So who knows, we may get reboot of 8043 as some point as well.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The [8043 Motorized Excavator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8043-1&name=Motorized%20Excavator&category=%5BTechnic%5D%5BModel%5D%5BConstruction%5D#T=P) from 2010 is retired, but in 2019, LEGO released the [42100 Liebherr R 9800](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42100-1#T=P), an excavator in the PoweredUP series of Technic models.

As of May 2021, the 42100 is still available in the [LEGO shop](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/liebherr-r-9800-excavator-42100), where the Liebherr co-branded excavator sells for $450 US and is described as:

> High-fidelity replica model, operated via the LEGO® TECHNIC™ CONTROL+ app and powered by 2 advanced Smart Hubs and 7 motors.

For comparison, the Bricklink price is about $225 for a used 8043 and about $700 for a new one (in May 2021).

[image: 42100 Liebherr excavator]